# Haskell non functions recursion (or value recursion or recursive let bindings)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm new to Haskell and reading Haskell from first principles.

in chapter 10 page 378 I came across with this new syntax

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

seems like fibs is a function bcs its being used or called on right

but its type is `fibs :: Num a => [a]` so its a value

how a value can be accessed inside it's own definition ?

if I do try to see what inside fibs, it just printout towards infinity.

and other example
`i = 1 + i` which is perfectly valid syntax,

but when I run it in side ghci it also halt it.

- what kind of recursion it is if its not recursion what it is ?
- what is the execution flow ?
- how `i` can can accessed on right side when its not been assigned at
  all ?
- what is the value of `i` for first time on right ?
- what is the value of `i` on right ?

any articles that can help ?

Comment: You're new to Haskell you are at chapter 10, page 378! Congratulations, you are really smart.

Comment: @Enlico Please highlight the issue what's wrong with question ?

Comment: as matter of fact I'm reading it page by page. but I did not see this type of  recursion any where before.

Comment: @hanan If you're learning a new language by reading a book, you'll probably see new things on (hopefully) a lot of the pages, and hopefully the surrounding text/pages explain it! I do not know the book, but I would guess that the point of that was to demonstrate a use of recursion that you might not have thought of from earlier definitions (it isn't actually any new syntax or language feature; just non-obvious consequences of things you've already learned about).

Answer (score 7):

In many (most?) languages functions are "special" values, which receive special status in the language syntax and semantics.

In Haskell, not so much. They share many properties with non-functions. In particular:

- We can pass functions (and non functions) as arguments to functions.
- We can return functions (and non functions) from functions.
- We can put functions (and non functions) into containers like lists, pairs, and so on.
- We can recursively define functions (and non functions).

The last point might be puzzling if you are not used to it, but there's no reason to allow recursion only when defining a function value in a lazy language like Haskell.

For instance one can define the infinite list `1:1:1:....` by letting `list = 1 : list`. If you can only understand recursive definitions for functions, just know that it is similar to `list() = 1 : list()`, except `list` is not a function, but a list.

You can also try to understand that `1:2:3:4:....` could be defined recursively as `list = 1 : map (+1) list`. Indeed, unfolding the definition we get:

```
list
= 1 : map (+1) list
= 1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) list)
= 1 : 2 : map (+1) (map (+1) list)
= 1 : 2 : map (+1) (map (+1) (1 : map (+1) list))
= 1 : 2 : 3 : map (+1) (map (+1) (map (+1) list))
...
```

Note that the above definition "works" because it can generate a part of the value before it recursively need its own value. In the `i = i + 1` example you mention, this does not happen, since `i + 1` needs the value of `i` immediately, before any part of the output can be produced. (Well, at least on the standard integer types.) Hence, it has the same behavior we would observe from an infinite recursive function such as `i() = i() + 1`.

Comment: Thanks What its called ? Nonfunction recursion? I did try to google it but there is not result

Comment: @hanan There is no specific name I know of, it's just recursion. Perhaps "recursion on values", "value recursion", but it's not a common term. You could try to google "lazy semantics" or "laziness" to understand it better: this kind of recursion is only meaningful in lazy (or non-strict) languages like Haskell. Otherwise, in an eager (or strict) language any non-function recursive definition would immediately cause non-termination, so language designers only allow recursion on functions.

Comment: @chi you show a call by name reduction, which is quadratic, but a call by need reduction sequence  of `list`  is linear.

Comment: @WillNess That's true. I'm unsure about the best way to explain this, though. CbName is less efficient, but looks a bit simpler to write. CbNeed is the "smart" way to compute it, but requires thinking about sharing. In my head, I don't use any of these but think about the denotational semantics, first, leaving the actual (non-strict) strategy as a lower level implementation detail. Well, until I need to reason about performance, that is ;-)

Comment: well I've settled on my way of showing this (as seen in my answer). it costs only one more line for the reduction sequence in your answer. :)

Comment: @WillNess Some sloppy and unspecified mental extensional view of programs. If I need to reason on bottoms, I do switch from sets to posets (maybe CPOs :-P). Of course, when programming I am never 100% formal for survival reasons. However, I find it useful to understand a recursive definition as a "limit" (supremum) of a sequence of approximations `_|_, 1:_|_, 1 : 2 : _|_, ...` which you get unfolding the recursion. Operational reasoning is also useful sometimes, but usually I prefer thinking "extensionally".

Comment: aha, thank you. I removed that part after re-reading your comment, since I gathered you do indeed think in these terms. :) but actually, "extensionally" i.e. value semantics, is also pretty descriptive here. but --- I stick to the naming game, since all too often I've found it all too confusing trying to think in terms of value substitutions. it becomes too deeply nested all too quickly, and I lose track / traction. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, `let` is what's known as `letrec` i.e. "recursive `let`" in other languages, meaning that *both* occurrences of a *name* in an equation refer to the *same* entity.

This makes sense as the equation is *not* an assignment, but a definition.<sup>(*)</sup>

```
fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
```

Here on the right `fibs` refers to the same `fibs` as the one on the left. It is not being called, but rather it is being used. It is being used according to its definition. It is defined with a lazy data constructor, `:`.

The evaluation can be imagined to proceed by *naming* all the interim entities and writing down their definitions according to what we already have:

```
print $ take 4 fibs ==>
take 4 fibs =
= take 4 (let {fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs} in fibs)
= take 4 (let {fibs = 1 : s1 ; s1 = scanl (+) 1 fibs} in fibs)
= take 4 (let {fibs = 1 : s1 ; s1 = scanl (+) 1 fibs} in (1 : s1))
= take 4 (1 : let {fibs = 1 : s1 ; s1 = scanl (+) 1 fibs} in s1)
= 1 : take 3 (let {fibs = 1 : s1 ; s1 = scanl (+) 1 fibs} in s1)
= 1 : take 3 (let {s1 = scanl (+) 1 (1 : s1)} in s1)
= 1 : take 3 (let {s1 = 1 : scanl (+) 2 s1} in s1)
= 1 : take 3 (let {s1 = 1 : s2; s2 = scanl (+) 2 s1} in (1 : s2))
= 1 : take 3 (1 : let {s1 = 1 : s2; s2 = scanl (+) 2 s1} in s2)
= 1 : 1 : take 2 (let {s1 = 1 : s2; s2 = scanl (+) 2 s1} in s2)
= 1 : 1 : take 2 (let {s2 = scanl (+) 2 (1 : s2)} in s2)
= 1 : 1 : take 2 (let {s2 = 2 : scanl (+) 3 s2} in s2)
= 1 : 1 : take 2 (let {s2 = 2 : s3; s3 = scanl (+) 3 s2} in (2 : s3))
= 1 : 1 : 2 : take 1 (let {s2 = 2 : s3; s3 = scanl (+) 3 s2} in s3)
= 1 : 1 : 2 : take 1 (let {s3 = scanl (+) 3 (2 : s3)} in s3)
= 1 : 1 : 2 : take 1 (let {s3 = 3 : scanl (+) 5 s3} in s3)
= 1 : 1 : 2 : take 1 (let {s3 = 3 : s4; s4 = scanl (+) 5 s3} in (3 : s4))
= 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : take 0 (let {s3 = 3 : s4; s4 = scanl (+) 5 s3} in s4)
= 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : [] 
= [1,1,2,3]
```

That's how it goes.<sup>(**)</sup>

The `i` in `let { i = i+1 } in i` uses `+` which is strict, so any attempt to use the value of `i` loops, as `+` demands the values of *both* its arguments before ever returning its value, unlike the lazy `:` which actually demands none.

---

You've asked,

> how a value can be accessed inside it's own definition ?

The above gives the answer, which is twofold. Firstly, because the (implied) `let` is recursive, both the names on the left and the right of the equal sign refer to the same entity. Secondly, since Haskell's evaluation is lazy, there are no assignments (and no "values" really in the usual sense) -- just definitions. A list is not a list, but a definition of a computational process to compute that list, etc.

---

<sub>(*) or in technical jargon, a *lazy* binding.</sub>

<sub>(**) turns out [it's a song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43FgE6uCyLw), and a nice one too.</sub>

Comment: were you comfortable following this? is something more still unclear? don't hesitate to ask for clarifications. :)

Comment: I think this is as clear as it can be. This `fibs` definition is a bit tricky to visualize at first, but following your steps one should get the general idea about how it's computed. (already +1'd)

Comment: @chi thanks for the feedback! :) (and as always, it became clearer to me too, after I wrote it here)

Comment: @chi BTW pseudocode with `where` instead of ``let`` can be [even clearer](https://pastebin.com/XUkZDbAc), I think. :) (the link is for your example's re-write, not mine)